# php: reuse variable value in multiple functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to reuse a variable value "$name1_info" declared in the function :informations() , in a second function : test().

I tried to use global variables but it doesn't work, i tried to add classes too but i can't in wordpress.

thanks for your help.

```
function createtab() {
?>
         <form id="#form" action="#v_form"  method="post" >
         <input  type="submit" name="informations" value="informations" />
         <input  type="submit" name="test" value="test" />
         </form>  
<?php

           if ( isset( $_POST["informations"] ) ) { informations ();} 
           if ( isset( $_POST["test"] ) ) {test(); }

        }




function informations (){


 ?>



    <form action="#v_form" method="post" id="v_form">
        <input  type="hidden" name="informations" value="informations" />
        <label for="hello"><h3>name1 </h3></label>
        <input type="text" name="name1" id="nom"  />
        <label for="assureur"><h3>name2</h3></label>
        <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />



    </form>

<?php

    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) ) {

        $name1_info = $_POST["name1"];
        $name2 =$_POST["name2"];          

    }        }




 function test(){
        Print($name1_info);

   }
```

Error messages : Undefined variable

Comment: You can create `class` in WordPress. On which file you are trying to create a class? If you are trying to create a class in `functions.php` then it doesn't work but you can create it in plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the var before assigning and before accessing as [**global**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). An example might help you.

```
global $var;
$var = 'Not called foo()';

function foo() {
    global $var;
    $var = "After calling foo()";
}

function bar()
{
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}

foo();
bar();
```

Note that, if you don't call foo() before calling bar() then value "after calling foo()" will not be assigned to $var.

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/EDMlc).

Answer (score 0):

well it is really hard to understand what you are trying to do, but either way, I recommend you to use `$GLOBALS['name1_info']`

and you should call `informations();` function first, in order to create and set this variable.

Hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Although using `global` might be common in Wordpress, I would suggest passing the value around wherever possible.  This works with 1 value, but can start to be more difficult with multiple values.  That is when using classes can help to encapsulate the related data.

So return the value from `informations()` and pass it in as a parameter to `test()`...

```
function createtab() {
    $name1_info = '';
    if ( isset( $_POST["informations"] ) ) { $name1_info = informations ();} 
    if ( isset( $_POST["test"] ) ) {test($name1_info); }

}

function informations (){
    $name1_info = '';
    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) ) {

        $name1_info = $_POST["name1"];
        $name2 =$_POST["name2"];          

    } 

    return $name1_info;
}

function test($name1_info){
        Print($name1_info);
}
```

As `$name1_info` is set conditionally, I've always set it to blank to ensure it's defined.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I click on test it shows me the value of "$ name1_info" defined in createtab ()

Comment: Do you mean the blank value or the value returned from the call to `informations()`?

Comment: the blank value, the first

Comment: the information() form  is displayed and the post works but does not change the value of "$ name1_info" in createtab ()

Comment: the error is  _Undefined variable: name1-info_ at this line **if ( isset( $_POST["test"] ) ) {test($name1_info);**